# How I can see total hours of all project that I logged in redmine

Tags: redmine

I have allotted 4 project and I want to see total hours that I spent in all project for specific month how can I get it ? please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this step :

```
1)open any task from redmine and click on spent time it will show you timing 
spent for that perticular Task.
2)Look it breadcrums it will like  "All Project >> your project name >> current task"
3)click on All project link from breadcrums.
4)Now you can see total time spent in all project after specific filter available on that page.
```

Hopefully you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no menu item in the default theme:

1. Browse to /time_entries
2. Add filter -> User -> is -> me

Answer (score 0):

go to http://url/time_entries 
It will show the time on all activities but click on "Report" tab
select "Month" and Add: "Project" it will display the total Time for each project you are part of month wise but if you just want to see yours then select user from the filter and select me and hit apply
you will see ur total hours spent for each project month wise